# feature.get(0).getinfo()[0] does not initialize inside function GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I have a list of features which I am going to use map.function to extract specific value from features but inside function when I am using `.getinfo()[0]` to return first value give me an error: `"Internal error: function argument not initialized."`

Let me know if anyone is familiar with this problem.

[image: structure of my features]

Here is the sample code:

```
var map_m = function(i) {
  i=ee.Number(i)
  var feature = ALL.get(i).getInfo()[0]
  var ff=feature
  
  return ff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide what `ALL` is, let me make assumptions and proceed.

```
var ALL =ee.List([[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]);
var map_m = function(i) { 
  i=ee.Number(i);
  var feature = ALL.get(i).getInfo()[0] ;
  var ff=feature;
  return ff 
  }
print(map_m(1));
```

First things first. Make sure you end every line with `;`. Use the last line of code to debug. I had no problem running the lines you provided. Please provide additional information to debug. Make sure when you pass argument to map_m, it should be within the limits, in my case, `0` or `1`. Did you call the function and pass the argument?

Comment: Thanks for responding Aman Jain. you are right. Its working. would you pleas check whats is wrong with following code.